# datetime inserted into database keep showing 1970-01-01 01:00:00 instead of inserted values

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I have created a form whereby users are allow to choose their own datetime. Also, I also allow users to have multiple datetime by using the appendchild method.
However, everytime when the user chose the datetime and submit the form, it will appear as 1970-01-01 01:00:00 in the database.
Following is my code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date[]')));

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO proposal(`date`, meeting_idmeeting, user_userid)
            VALUES ('$date', $id, 1);";
```

This is the HTML code:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="date">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8" id="date2">
                            <input type="datetime-local" name="date[]" class="form-control" id="date"/>
                            <span class="error"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Can anybody let me know what went wrong?

Comment: make sure $date is actually holding a date string that can be inserted, e.g. `var_dump($date)` before the insert. Or use a debugger. And please learn about prepared statements and sql injection.

Comment: why are you using `input type="datetime-local"` when there are plenty of javascript datepicker libraries are available??

Answer (score 0):

You are taking array dates. But you are trying only a date. Try this,

```
$dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date[]')));

foreach($dates as $date) {
    //exec insert query....
}
```

If you insert just a date, try this;

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO proposal(`date`, meeting_idmeeting, user_userid)
            VALUES ('" .$date[0] . "', $id, 1);";
```